# Python No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a Python novice who started to touch on matplotlib today. But when i try the first little demo there is a problem. My computer is Windows7 64 bit, Python3.5. I followed the order on the matplotlib website:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Which results in:

[image]

My program：

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
plt.plot(squares)
plt.show()
```

The error I am getting:

`error：No module named 'matplotlib'`

Comment: You might have two version of Python installed on your PC. You may have installed matplotlib on one of them but then you are using the other version to run the code. Check that you only have one version of Python installed.

Comment: In addition, it looks like you've installed Python (and the matplotlib module) with the "just for me" option under your administrator account. Are you running your code under the same account?

Comment: The first time I encountered this problem a bit overwhelmed.My computer has only one account.Also in the cmd command, enter the Python display only one version of how do I continue to deal with?thank you .@DavidG@whrrgarbl

Comment: Matplotlib has been installed on the version of Python that is located in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32. Is that the version of Python you are using to run the code?

Comment: My guess is that your computer already had python installed (in the path shown in your question). You may not have realised and so installed another version of Python.

Comment: I checked there really did two versions as you said I started trying to use anaconda @DavidG